# Adding selector for multiple control events UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

Can I add a selector for multiple control events in one line?

Something like `[_recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:) forControlEvents:@[UIControlEventTouchDragExit,UIControlEventTouchUpInside]];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control events are bitflags:

```
[_recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit|UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add selector for multiple control events using bitmask.

```
[_recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myaction:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchDragExit | UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
```